# "shape" as an uncountable noun

Tags: grammar

Example with a context ([The Object-Oriented Thought Process by Matt Weisfeld, 3rd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672330164)):

> This is an interesting issue. If we did want the Shape class to contain the code for all possible **shape** present and future, some conditional statement (like a Case statement) would be required. This would be very messy and difficult to maintain. This is one example of where the strength of an object-oriented design comes into play.

I just can't wrap my head around why *shape* is used as an uncountable noun in this passage. Why is it not *shapes* which is what the Shape class is supposed to be all about—drawing many different geometrical shapes on screen? We're talking plural here.

Comment: I dunno. I read it. I accept it. I move on. I don't let every single possible usage stop me in my tracks.

Comment: I guess it's possible as written, but *shapes* seems like a better choice.  Maybe it's a typo.

Comment: I would accept the singular more readily if it were capitalised- so as to refer to class Shape, otherwise I agree that “shapes” is better.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking folks to speculate as to why a particular text uses a word as an uncountable noun, when we cannot look into the mind of the author/editor and discover why.

Comment: @pazzo: I disagree. I don't think it's speculation at all. This isn't literature or some other artistic context we're talking about here, where the author might have highly symbolic and personal reasons for choosing a particular phrasing. This is an instructive technical work and one would expect the author to use quite straightforward (if technical) language.

Comment: It's almost certainly a typo; and I'd guess that it originally read ***every** possible shape* and was later changed to *all*, without tidying up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's almost certainly a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is a simple error. I cannot think of any reason, any nuanced meaning, for "shape" to be used as an uncountable noun. A simple typographical error seems far more likely than this author trying to use a word in an unexpected way without explanation!

Comment: Which is your speculation...

Comment: @pazzo: Yes, but not speculation as to *the author's mindset*, but speculation as to *how the English language is being used here*.